# VHDL unnecessary value after (to_unsigned) conversion

Tags: for-loop, integer, vhdl, unsigned

I use a for loop:

```
for l in 0 to 2 loop
```

and inside I want to have at some point 2 when `l=0`, 1 when `l=1` and 0 when `l=2`. How can I do that? I used:

```
to_integer(unsigned(not(std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(l,2)))))
```

[which seems too complicated] but there is an error at simulations. I think because the final integer can also take the value 3. The error is:

> Value 3 is out of range 0 to 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
point := 2 - l ; -- where l is the loop index
```